# Delphi5 and Indy 10 posting within a thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, indy10, delphi-5

I have an old Delphi 5 app that I had to finally upgrade to Indy 10. Thanks to the folks here, that is now complete. All of my Indy posts runs inside of a thread unit:

```
TInetThread = class(TThread)
```

and the posting code is done in the Execute of the thread

```
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
```

The basic posting is done like this

```
  {TLS}HTTP.Post(URL,ssSource,ssResult);
  HTTP.Disconnect;
```

Only a total of three threads can ever run at a time. The problem is, when running (debugging in the IDE) when the second thread launches and the post is not yet complete in the first thread, the application basically freezes on the second post (still can click around but have to use the IDE Run Reset to close it.

The good news is the application runs just fine by itself outside the IDE.

I was wondering if this is just a bug with Indy 10 and the older Delphi 5 (as Indy 9 didn't do this) or maybe something I haven't setup properly for posting in a thread with Indy 10. It is only bothersome when attempting to debug something, an inconvenient not being about to run multiple posts when running in the IDE.

Any ideas?

--------------- As per Requested ------------------------------

Here is how I start the threads. Thread 1 always completes one post before launching the other threads if there are more posts to process.

```
    for i := 0 to Sending.Strings.Count - 1 do
  Begin
    RecordMessage(1,'Looking at record ' + IntToStr(i));
    If HangupConnection > 0 then Break;//Someone clicked Hangup
    If NetconnectRecordQualifies(i) then
    Begin
      NetConnect := (pos('Internet',DataModule1.XDeptDB.FieldByName('Script').AsString) > 0);
      If NetConnect then
      Begin
        DataModule1.ReportsDB.Tag := 0;
        LastDept := DataModule1.XDeptDB.FieldByName('Department').AsString;
        TheReport := '';
        If (MyThread1 = nil) and (IThread1Done = true) then
        Begin
          IThread1Done := false;
          StartNetConnectReportThread(1);
        end;
        If (MyThread1 <> nil) and (MyThread1.Bureau = 0) and (pos('AccessPoint',XPRUrl) <> 0) then break;
        delay(0.5);
        If (MyThread2 = nil) and (IThread2Done = true) and (StandardProVersion in [1,3,8,9]) and (HangupConnection = 0) then
        Begin
          If NetconnectRecordQualifies(i) then
          Begin
            IThread2Done := false;
            StartNetConnectReportThread(2);
          end;
        end;
        delay(0.5);
        If (MyThread3 = nil) and (IThread3Done = true) and (StandardProVersion in [1,3,8,9]) and (HangupConnection = 0) then
        Begin
          If NetconnectRecordQualifies(i) then
          Begin
            IThread3Done := false;
            StartNetConnectReportThread(3);
          end;
        end;
        If (IThread1Done = false) and (IThread2Done = false) and (IThread3Done = false) then break; // ea2000.6.2:
      end;
    end;
  end;
```

When creating the threads, I basically see how many threads have been already created and continue to create them as demand exists, up to 3.

```
procedure TDataModule1.StartNetConnectReportThread(ThreadNumber: Integer);

  procedure DoThreadNow(var Thread: TInetThread);
  var
    i,i2,i4 : Integer;
    Eaw98ini : TIniFile;
  Begin
    Thread := TInetThread.Create(True); //create suspend cause we´ve got to set
    Thread.FreeOnTerminate := True;
    Thread.OnTerminate := IThreadComplete;
    Thread.ReadTimeOut := HTTPReadTimeOut;
    Thread.ProxyPort := ProgProxyPort;
    Thread.ProxyUsername := ProgProxyUserName;
    Thread.ProxyPassword := ProgProxyPassword;
    Thread.ProxyServer := ProgProxyServer;
    Thread.ProxyBasicAuth := ProgProxyBasicAuth;

    If ReadStringCol(2,TUCertFile) <> '' then Thread.CertPassword := ReadStringCol(2,TUCertFile) else
      Thread.CertPassword := 'XXXXXXXXX';//Set as default for now.  Soon, I won't set it.
    If Bur = '0' then
    Begin
      RecordMessage(1,'[Experian]['+IntToStr(ThreadNumber)+'] Preparing ' +
        DataModule1.XInquiryDBLastName.AsString);
      //LastNetConnectURLCheck := Now;//moved above to the try section.  This caused the failure of every being
                                     //able to check the last time when ECALS was checked
      Thread.URL := Url;
      Thread.Password := DataModule1.XDeptDBField16.AsString;
      Thread.Username := DataModule1.XDeptDBField12.AsString;
      Thread.Inquiry := '';
      Thread.FormatReport := ((DataModule1.GetOutputType(2) = '10') or (FN(5,'reports')[2] = '4'));
      Thread.CertPassword := '';
      Thread.ReportString := FN(5,'Reports');
      Thread.Dept := FN(5,'Department');
    end else 

    [.....]

    Thread.InquiryRecNo := DataModule1.XInquiryDBUniqueNumber.AsInteger;
    Thread.InquiryName := DataModule1.XInquiryDBLastName.AsString;
    Thread.ThreadNo := ThreadNumber;
    Thread.Resume;
  end;

begin
  If ThreadNumber = 1 then DoThreadNow(MyThread1) else
    If ThreadNumber = 2 then DoThreadNow(MyThread2) else
    If ThreadNumber = 3 then DoThreadNow(MyThread3);
end;
```

Here is most of the actual thread. Again, everything runs right if just executing the program. Locks up when running the program within the IDE and only when running multi thread. If just creating one thread, it runs fine in the IDE.

I had to strip out a lot of code due to my security agreements with the credit bureaus, but the error happens when posting in a 2nd thread.

```
unit Ithread;

interface

uses
  Classes,IdIntercept, IdSSLOpenSSL, IdHTTP, IdException, SysUtils,
  IDComponent, MyUtils, IdURI, Dialogs, idAuthentication, IdAuthenticationDigest,
  IdAuthenticationSSPI, IdHeaderList;

type
  TInetThread = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure DisplayTheMessage;
    procedure HTTPStatus(axSender: TObject;
      const axStatus: TIdStatus; const asStatusText: String);
    function SSLVerifyPeer(Certificate: TIdX509): Boolean;
    procedure SSLGetPassword(var Password: String);
    procedure HTTPWorkEnd(Sender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode);
    procedure HTTPWorkBegin(Sender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
      const AWorkCountMax: Integer);
    procedure HTTPSelectAuthorization(Sender: TObject;
      var AuthenticationClass: TIdAuthenticationClass;
      AuthInfo: TIdHeaderList);
    procedure SSLStatusInfo(Msg: String);

  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    ReadTimeout, LastBureau, VerifyCertificate, ProxyPort, TheImageIndex, Bureau,
      ThreadNo, InquiryRecNo: Integer;
    CertPassword, ProxyServer, ProxyUsername, ProxyPassword, ErrorText, BureauName, TheMessage,
      LastXPRUrl, LastXPRTestUrl, Report, InquiryName, UserName, Password, URL, Inquiry, ReportString, Dept: String;
    PostStart, ConnectTime, PostTime, StartTime: Double;
    MsgDuration: Word;
    TestURL, FormatReport, ProxyBasicAuth, SentImages, GotSSLError: Boolean;
    HTTP, HTTP1, HTTP2, HTTP3: TIdHTTP;
    SSL: TIDSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    procedure GotTheNetConnect;
    Function IsRealPost: Boolean;
  end;

var
  IThread1Done, iThread2Done, iThread3Done: Boolean;
  IThreadErrorCount: Integer;

implementation

uses
  Globals;


procedure TInetThread.DisplayTheMessage;
Begin
  GlobalSplash.UpdateStatusCaption('['+BureauName+']['+IntToStr(ThreadNo)+'] ' + TheMessage, MsgDuration);
  If (not SentImages) and (TheImageIndex <> -1) then
    GlobalSplash.UpdateStatusImageIndex(TheImageIndex);
  MsgDuration := 0
end;

procedure TInetThread.GotTheNetConnect;
Begin
  //While ThreadIsPostingRecord do mydelay(100);
  //Showmessage('start');
  //ThreadIsPostingRecord := true;
  Inquiry := '';
  GlobalSplash.GotNetConnect(ThreadNo);
  //Showmessage('end');
  //ThreadIsPostingRecord := false;
end;

procedure TInetThread.Execute;
var
  MyList: TStringList;
  SendingMultipleSSNDecodes: Boolean;
  ssSource, ssResult: TStringStream;
  Line, Attempt, i: Integer;
  LastURL, TestInitial, s, s2: String;
  UseSSL, LoginSuccessful: Boolean;

  label TryToLogOnAgain, LogOnNow, FinishUp;


  procedure DisplayMsg(Msg: String);
  Begin
    TheMessage := Msg;
    Synchronize(DisplayTheMessage);
  end;

  procedure StatusImageIndex(Index: Integer);
  Begin
    TheImageIndex := Index;
    Synchronize(DisplayTheMessage);
  end;

  procedure CreateSSL;
  Begin
    {IF ThreadNo = 1 then HTTp1 := TIdHttp.Create(nil) else
      if ThreadNo = 2 then HTTp2 := TIdHttp.Create(nil) else
      if ThreadNo = 3 then HTTp3 := TIdHttp.Create(nil);
    IF ThreadNo = 1 then http := http1 else
      if ThreadNo = 2 then http:= http2 else
      if ThreadNo = 3 then http:= http3;}
    HTTp := TIdHttp.Create(nil);
    HTTP.OnSelectAuthorization := HTTPSelectAuthorization;
    HTTP.HTTPOptions := [hoInProcessAuth,hoForceEncodeParams,hoKeepOrigProtocol];

    HTTP.OnStatus := HTTPStatus;
    //Indy 10 HTTP.OnWorkBegin := HTTPWorkBegin;
    HTTP.OnWorkEnd := HTTPWorkEnd;
    HTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    HTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyPort := ProxyPort;
    HTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyServer := ProxyServer;

    HTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyUsername := ProxyUserName;
    HTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyPassword := ProxyPassword;
    HTTP.ProxyParams.BasicAuthentication := ProxyBasicAuth;
    If UseSSL then
    Begin
      SSL := TIDSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
      // Indy 10 ssl.OnStatusInfo := SSLStatusInfo;
      SSL.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
      SSL.OnGetPassword := SSLGetPassword;
//      SSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;sslvTLSv1
      //Indy 10: {TLS}SSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
      {TLS}SSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
      {If (Bureau = 0) and (VerifyCertificate = 1) then
      Begin
        SSL.OnVerifyPeer := SSLVerifyPeer;
        SSL.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [sslvrfPeer];
      end;}
      HTTP.IOHandler := SSL;
    end;
  end;
Begin
  TheImageIndex := -1;
  VerifyCertificate := 0;
  SentImages := false;
  Report := '';
  Attempt := 0;
  MsgDuration := 0;
  If {(StartParams[4] = '1') and //6.5.6.3} IsRealPost then
    DisplayMsg('Creating HTTP, SSL and Result streams');
  ssSource := TStringStream.Create('');
  ssResult := TStringStream.Create('');
  MyList := TStringList.Create;

  Try
    LastBureau := -1;

    LogOnNow:
    GotSSLError := false;
    UseSSL := {true;} uppercase(copy(URL,5,1)) = 'S';

    Begin
      If HTTP <> nil then
      Begin
        HTTP.Free;
        HTTP := nil;
      end;
      If SSL <> nil then
      Begin
        SSL.Free;
        SSL := nil;
      end;
      CreateSSL;
      If (Bureau = 0) and ((VerifyCertificate = 1) or (not IsRealPost)) then LastBureau := -1 else
        LastBureau := Bureau;
    end;
    If (Bureau = 0) and Isrealpost and (pos('&NETCONNECT_TRANSACTION',Inquiry) = 0) then
    Begin
      MyList.Text := TIdURI.PathEncode(Inquiry);
      MyList.Text := StringReplace(MyList.Text, #13#10, '%0A', [rfReplaceall]);
      MyList.Text := StringReplace(MyList.Text, #9, '%09', [rfReplaceall]);
      MyList.Text := StringReplace(MyList.Text, '?', '%3F', [rfReplaceall]);
      MyList.Text := StringReplace(MyList.Text, '=', '%3D', [rfReplaceall]);
      MyList.Text := StringReplace(MyList.Text, '"', '%22', [rfReplaceall]);
      MyList.Text := StringReplace(MyList.Text, '/', '%2F', [rfReplaceall]);
      MyList.Text := '&NETCONNECT_TRANSACTION=' + MyList.Text;
      Inquiry := MyList.Text
    end;

    If Bureau in [0,1] then
    Begin
      If Bureau = 0 then BureauName := 'Experian' else BureauName := 'Equifax';
      If UseSSL then
      With SSL.SSLOptions do
      Begin
        CertFile := '';
        KeyFile := '';
        RootCertFile := '';
      end;
    end else
    If Bureau = 2 then
    Begin
      BureauName := 'TransUnion';
      {If TestURL then TestInitial := 't' else }TestInitial := '';//6.4.3.0: Only using root.pem for both test and prod
      If UseSSL then With SSL.SSLOptions do
      Begin
        If CertFile <> PgmDir + TestInitial + 'cert.pem' then CertFile := PgmDir + TestInitial + 'cert.pem';
        If KeyFile <> PgmDir + TestInitial + 'custkey.key' then KeyFile := PgmDir + TestInitial + 'custkey.key';
        If RootCertFile <> PgmDir + TestInitial + 'root.pem' then RootCertFile := PgmDir + TestInitial + 'root.pem';
      end;
    end;

    TryToLogOnAgain:
    DisplayMsg('Trying to log in again');
    StartTime := Time;
    If (InquiryCount = 1) or (InquiryCount = 951) then LapTime := 0;
    ssResult.Position := 0;
    ssResult.WriteString('');
    ssSource.Position := 0;
    ssSource.WriteString('');
    HTTP.Request.Username := UserName;
    HTTP.Request.Password := Password;
    HTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := ((HTTP.Request.Username <> '') or (HTTP.Request.Password <> ''));
    Http.ReadTimeout := ReadTimeout{20000};
    Http.ConnectTimeout := ReadTimeout{6.4.1.3 Beta 1};
    {If (StartParams[4] = '1' then//6.5.6.3} DisplayMsg('Setting ReadTimeout: ' + IntToStr(ReadTimeout));
    If Terminated then Exit;

    If {(StartParams[4] = '1') and//6.5.6.3} IsRealPost then
      DisplayMsg('Assigning inquiry');

    If (pos('LOOKUP', uppercase(Url)) = 0) then //I do not want to send the Inquiry too the lookup URL
    begin
      If pos('|',Inquiry) > 0 then
      begin
        InquiryName := copy(Inquiry,1,pos(';',Inquiry)-1);
        Inquiry := Copy(Inquiry,pos(';',Inquiry)+1,length(Inquiry));
        ssSource.WriteString(Copy(Inquiry,1,pos('|',Inquiry)-1));
        Inquiry := copy(Inquiry,pos('|',Inquiry)+1,length(Inquiry));
      end else
      Begin
        Displaymsg(Inquiry);
        ssSource.WriteString(Inquiry);
        Displaymsg('lWriteString to ssSource complete');
        {Inquiry := '';}
      end;
    end;
    Try
      ErrorText := '';
      DisplayMsg('posting start time');
      PostStart := Time;
      {If (StartParams[4] = '1') then//6.5.6.3}
      Begin
        IF IsRealPost then DisplayMsg('OK.  Sending Post') else
        Begin
          If (pos('AccessPoint',URL) > 0) then DisplayMsg('Getting URL') else
          If (VerifyCertificate > 0) then DisplayMsg('Verifying Certificate');
          ssSource.Position := 0;
          ssSource.WriteString(' ');
        end;
      end;

       {If (StartParams[4] = '1') or (PgmOptions[25] = '2') then//6.5.6.3} DisplayMsg('Posting to: ' + URL);
      Attempt := Attempt + 1;
      {If (StartParams[4] = '1')  or (PgmOptions[25] = '2') then//6.5.6.3}
      Begin
        If Bureau = 0 then DisplayMsg(StringReplace(ssSource.DataString,'XXXXXXXX','XXXXXXXX',[rfReplaceAll])) else
          DisplayMsg(ssSource.DataString);
      end;
      LastURL := URL;
      //
      //
      //HTTP.DoRequest(hmPost,{URL}'https:// ... [Credit Bureau won't allow me to post urls for some sort of security reason]',ssSource,ssResult);//This will not disconnect if already connected like the post
      // Indy 10{TLS}HTTP.DoRequest(hmPost,{'https:... [Credit Bureau won't allow me to post urls for some sort of security reason]'}URL,ssSource,ssResult);
      {TLS}HTTP.Post(URL,ssSource,ssResult);
      HTTP.Disconnect;

      If {(StartParams[4] = '1') and//6.5.6.3} IsRealPost then
       if FormatReport then  DisplayMsg('Got Post, Formating') else DisplayMsg('Got Post, Not Formatting');
      PostTime := Time - (PostStart + ConnectTime);
      ssSource.Position := 0;
      ssSource.WriteString('');
    Except
      on E: EIdException do
      Begin
        s := ''; {6.4.1.3 beta1}
        If VerifyCertificate = 2 then
        Begin
          DisplayMsg('Certificate Verified');
          Attempt := Attempt - 1;
        end else
        Begin
          GotSSLError := true;
          If pos('TIMEOUT',uppercase(E.Message)) = 0 then
          Begin
            {6.4.1.3 Beta 1} //Attempt := 3; //Don't do over unless it is a timeout.
            If (Bureau = 0) and (pos('AccessPoint',URL) = 0) then
            Begin
              If pos('403',E.Message) > 0 then s := E.Message +#13#10+
                '  The Net Connect User ID and Password in this department ('+Dept+') are currently Not Authorized ' +#13#10+
                '  for access to the Experian Net Connect product. Please correct before sending again.' else
              If (pos('302',E.Message) > 0) or (pos('303',E.Message) > 0{6.5.3.4}) then s := E.Message +#13#10+
                '  The Net Connect User ID and/or Password in this department ('+Dept+') are incorrect.' +#13#10+
                '  Your Net Connect password may also be expired or has been disabled by Experian.' +#13#10+
                '  See http://easyaccessonline.com/?p=842 for more information.'+#13#10
              else s := E.Message;
            end else
            If (Bureau = 2) then
            Begin
              If (pos('500',E.Message) > 0) then s := E.Message +#13#10+
                '  The most common reasons for getting a HTTP 500 error from TransUnion' +#13#10+
                '  is because your TUNA2 Certificate has expired or your IP Address has changed.' +#13#10+
                '  See http://easyaccessonline.com/?p=4223 for more information.'+#13#10
              else s := E.Message;
            end else s := E.Message;
          end else s := E.Message;
          if s = '' then ErrorText := 'ERROR: Unknown HTTP Exception. Possible Firewall/Proxy error.' else {6.4.1.3 beta1}
            ErrorText := 'ERROR: ' + s;
          IThreadErrorCount := IThreadErrorCount + 1;
          MsgDuration := 2;
          If VerifyCertificate <> 0 then
          Begin
            case VerifyCertificate of
              3: DisplayMsg('Certificate Invalid - Missing experian.com');
              4: DisplayMsg('Certificate Invalid - Not yet Valid');
              5: DisplayMsg('Certificate Invalid - Expired');
              6: DisplayMsg('Certificate Invalid - URL missing from certificate');
              7: DisplayMsg('Certificate Invalid - Not a Trusted Root Certification Authority');
            end;
          end;
          DisplayMsg(ErrorText);
        end;
      end;
      on E: Exception do ErrorText := 'ERROR: ' + E.Message; {6.4.1.3 beta3}
    end;
    {Get the Result}

    If GotSSLError and (Attempt < 3) then
    Begin
      DisplayMsg('Resending Inquiry.  Attempt ' + IntToStr(Attempt+1) + ' of 3');
      GotSSLError := false;
      Goto TryToLogOnAgain;
      Exit;
    end;

    If VerifyCertificate > 0 then
    Begin
      If VerifyCertificate > 2 then Goto FinishUp;
      VerifyCertificate := 0;
      Goto LogOnNow;
    end;
    ssResult.Position := 0;
    s := '';
    {If (StartParams[4] = '1') then//6.5.6.3}
    Begin
      //This will remove the unprintable char's before I display them.  Experian and TU Acquire send unprintable chars.
      for i := 1 to Length(ssResult.DataString) do
      if ssResult.DataString[i] in [#8..#255] then s := s + ssResult.DataString[i];
      DisplayMsg('Received: '+s);
      s:= ''; //6.5.4.1: Was causing a double TU report because the variable wasn't cleared when debug was turned on
    end;
    s2 := '';

    If Bureau = 0 then
    Begin
      {This code strips out all of the #0 (null) charicters that XPR sends.  This took a bit to figure
      out.  I am hoping it takes other companys longer.}
      ssResult.Position := 0;
      While (ssResult.Position + 1) <= ssResult.Size do
      Begin
        s := ssResult.ReadString(1);
        If s[1] in [#1..#255] then s2 := s2 + s;
      end;
      If (pos('AccessPoint',URL) > 0) then
      begin
        if uppercase(Copy(s2,1,4)) <> 'HTTP' then
        //6.5.5.5: If Experian fails to return a Net Connect URL then I will set it myself
        begin
          DisplayMsg('Experian''s ECALS Failed to return a valid URL');
          DisplayMsg('Easy Access is setting Net Connect URL instead');
          {if TestURL then s2 := 'https://dm1.experian.com/netconnect2_0Demo/servlets/NetConnectServlet' else
            s2 := 'https://ss3.experian.com/netconnect2_0/servlets/NetConnectServlet';}
          if TestURL then s2 := LastXPRTestURL else s2 := LastXPRURL;
        end else
        begin
          if TestURL then LastXPRTestURL := s2 else LastXPRURL := s2;
        end;
        DisplayMsg('Now posting to: ' + s2);
      end;

      [process the return]

    end;


    FinishUp:
    If CurrentlyPostingRecord then Goto FinishUp;
    {If (StartParams[4] = '1') then//6.5.6.3}
      DisplayMsg('ready to process ' + InquiryName);
    Synchronize(GotTheNetConnect);
    Attempt := 0;
    verifycertificate := 0;
    If Inquiry <> '' then Goto LogonNow;
  Finally
    If UseSSL then With SSL.SSLOptions do
    Begin
      CertFile := '';
      KeyFile := '';
      RootCertFile := '';
    end;
    If MyList <> nil then MyList.Free;
    MyList := nil;
    If SSL <> nil then SSL.Free;
    SSL := nil;
    If HTTP <> nil then HTTP.Free;
    HTTP := nil;
    If ssResult <> nil then ssResult.Free;
    If ssSource <> nil then ssSource.Free;
    {if (StartParams[4] = '1') then//6.5.6.3}
      GlobalSplash.UpdateStatusCaption('['+BureauName+']['+
      IntToStr(ThreadNo)+'] Closing Thread',0);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows how you are using the threads. Your description does not make sense, and I have never seen any versuon of the IDE behave like that.

Comment: The Thread is pretty long but I will try to skim it down to just the Thread Class with it's properties and the Execute procedure but will still have to strip stuff out of that. What doesn't make sense is why it would run outside of Delphi but lockup as soon as it tries to make another post while another thread is in the middle of a post. If I code the app for only one thread it run's fine in the IDE. As soon as I code it for 3 threads, locks up on the second thread but runs file just launching the app by itself. I will have to do this Monday. No big deal but it will continue to bother me.

Comment: Using the debugger changes timing. If you have a latent defect in your code, the timing changes could expose a race condition that causes undefined behaviour. _Of course there is also the possibility that the debugger is buggy_. But even so, this is not something you'll want to disregard too lightly. If there is a latent defect in your code: Murphy's Law states that it will find the most inopportune moment for the timing to be just right to cause the most spectacularly horrible and costly failure.

Comment: Yes. Probably a defect in your code. Threading defects are often intermittent. Natural human wishful thinking means you want to hope that the debugger is to blame. However you should doubt yourself.

Comment: Provide some code how you create and synchronize your thtreads.

Comment: Well, before I totally embarrass myself and post my code, how would I go about it since it won't fit into a comment? Second, I am going to see if I can go line by line and see if there is something that I possibly missed. But I have to agree with Craig. During my installation of Indy 10, I set a couple of conditions that a consumer probably would never set but found a bug. I couldn't let it go. 12 hours later I found the problem and fixed it. It has never been found in the field, but my luck if it was, it probably would have been caught by a big customer like BofA.

Comment: Don't add the code, or other details, in comments. Use the "**edit**" button, just under the tags of your question, to edit your question.

Comment: Well, the problem is the Synchronize(DisplayTheMessage). When running in a thread, I tried to trace the thread but the trace always stops on one of the Synchronize(DisplayTheMessage) lines with no error, just locks up. So I then decided to trace what the DisplayTheMessage actually called on my main form and traced that procedure on the main form. The post went through. I guess by tracing the main form it slowed things down enough to finish the thread. Only happens within the IDE. Runs fine as a compiled app and use to run fine with indy9's thread. Not willing to loose the DisplayTheMessage.